# Time difference in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
 var time_1 = '13:44:25:912';
 var time_2 = '14:45:30:910';
 var inTime=time_1.split(":");
 var outTime= time_2.split(":");
 var hr = outTime[0] - inTime[0];
 var min = ((outTime[1] - inTime[1])+hr*60)%60;
 var sec = ((outTime[2] - inTime[2])+min*60)%60;
 var milli = ((outTime[3] - inTime[3])+sec*1000)%1000;

 document.write(milli);
 document.write("<br>"+sec);
 document.write("<br>"+min);
 document.write("<br>"+hr);
```

Hey Friends I am need to find time difference in milliseconds I am able to get the difference in HH:MM:SS:Milli now i have convert all into milli plz help for the same

Comment: Use split on the strings and create new Date objects out of them. Then just do date1.getTime()-date2.getTime()

Comment: Or `milli + 1000 * sec + 1000 * 60 * min + ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

total milliseconds would be `milli + (sec * 1000) + (min * 60000) + (hr * 3600000)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) function to get the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC. You need to pass a date-part to the string, but it doesn't really matter as long as you keep it the same in both strings.

**JavaScript**

```
var time1 = Date.parse("01 Jan 2000 13:44:25:912"),
    time2 = Date.parse("01 Jan 2000 14:45:30:910");

console.log(time2 - time1);
```

**Output**

```
3664998
```

See [`jsFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/nw0k999w/)